# Regular expression for parsing a file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I wish to parse a file as described below.
I want to select the line which begins by H until the line finishing by `//`.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work and return 1:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $nom='';
# Declare and initialize variables
my $annotation = '';
my $dna = '';
my $record = '';
my $filename = 'ess.txt';
my $i=0;
my $save_input_separator = $/;
open(GBFILE, $filename) or die "Error";

# Set input separator to "//\n" and read in a record to a
#scalar
{
  $/="//\n";
  $record = <GBFILE>;
}
$/ = $save_input_separator;
$nom=($record=~ /(.*)\/\/\n/s);
print $nom;
exit;
```

This is the input:

```
H ANDN920101

D alpha-CH chemical shifts (Andersen et al., 1992)

R LIT:1810048b PMID:1575719

A Andersen, N.H., Cao, B. and Chen, C.

T Peptide/protein structure analysis using the chemical shift index method: 

upfield alpha-CH values reveal dynamic helices and aL sites

J Biochem. and Biophys. Res. Comm. 184, 1008-1014 (1992)
C BUNA790102 0.949

I A/L R/K N/M D/F C/P Q/S E/T G/W H/Y I/V

4.35 4.38 4.75 4.76 4.65 4.37 4.29 3.97 4.63 3.95

4.17 4.36 4.52 4.66 4.44 4.50 4.35 4.70 4.60 3.95

//
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by parsing? Which fields do you want to store? How do you want to store it? Do you really want to parse only one record, which is what you do now? There's so many questions here, I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Is it because there's no newline after `//` but your code expects it?

Comment: rather than `$save_input_separator` you can use `local $/ = ....` within you closure to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use `my $result = ($input =~ /H(.+?)\/\//)` ?

Also keep in mind that number variables store the last successful matches that you had. Usually those are used in
`if ($input =~ /some_regex/)`

Then the expression will evaluate to 1 if `TRUE`
and $1,$2,... will store your matches, which is why you possibly get 1 as output.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $nom = '';


# Declare and initialize variables

my $record = '';
my $filename = 'ess.txt';
open(GBFILE, $filename) or die "Error";

# Set input separator to "//\n" and read in a record to a
#scalar

my @val = <GBFILE>;

foreach my $val (@val)
{
$val =~ /(^H.*)..(\/\/)/;
$record .= $val if($val);
}
print "Start +++ $record +++ End";

exit;
```